# Как сделать скриншот элемента формы

Tags: c#, winforms, form, screenshots

Есть элемент Webbrowser. Как сделать его скриншот? Не используя метод DrawToBitmap.

Использую этот код, но он сохраняет всю форму.

```
this.Opacity = 0;
Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);

// create the bitmap to copy the screen shot to
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

// now copy the screen image to the graphics device from the bitmap
using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    gr.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);          
}
this.Opacity = 100;
```

Comment: Возможно через WM_PRINT где подсунуть ему CompatibleBitmap для отрисовки.

Answer (score 3):

Непонятно, зачем вы меняете свойство Opacity, с какой целью?

А так, всё просто:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(webBrowser.Width, webBrowser.Height);

using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    gr.CopyFromScreen(webBrowser.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, webBrowser.Size);
}

bitmap.Save("screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Единственное, на что следует обратить внимание: нужно методом PointToScreen преобразовать координаты компонента в координаты экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Есть ответ на похожий вопрос на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/266139/4278250)

Допустим Ваш `WebBrowser` называется `webBrowser1`:

```
Control control = webBrowser1;
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);
control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, control.ClientRectangle);
```

Comment: А вы сами код проверяли? Работает? Боюсь, что нет. Дело в том, что DrawToBitmap корректно отрабатывает только с управляемыми контролами, а WebBrowser - обёртка над неуправляемым компонентом. Недаром он не поддерживает этот метод.